# Return custom object AND controlling response code in JAX-RS

Tags: jersey

I'm using JAX-RS in my web application to return my own object.
I want to keep doing it, but I want to set the HTTP response code (e.g. 401 for unauthorized, etc.).
From the information I've found it seems like I have to return the type Response and not my custom object.
Is that correct?

My current code (simplified) - when **MyReponse** is an object that Jaxb knows how to deal with:

```
@POST
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML , MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public MyResponse RegisterUser (
        @FormParam("userName") String userName,
        @FormParam("password") String password) {
    // add user logic
    return new MyResponse(....<params to ctor...);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right.

You'll need to use something like:

```
@POST
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML , MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response RegisterUser (
    @FormParam("userName") String userName,
    @FormParam("password") String password) {
    // add user logic
    return Response.status(401).entity(new MyResponse(...)).build();
}
```

see http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html#d4e355 (and other chapters) for additional useful information.

Comment: I know I am late to the party, but I wanted to post a comment..while you can certainly do it as Pavel describes, you could get the best of both worlds if you used exceptions.  Your method would return type MyObject, and in your 401 example you would throw a WebApplicationException and populate the status code and entity body.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7959366/2025882 for an example.

Comment: @Mike
I'm getting error 500 when I do this,
whats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend Response class and return your custom status when you override `getStatus()` method.